# Alternative to try, catch, finally in Haxe

Tags: haxe

In AS3 I could try/catch/finally a JSON file as follows:

```
try{
    myJSON = JSON.parse(_fileReference.data.toString());
}
catch (e:TypeError){ //String?
    _se.log.trace(e); //Never got called
}
finally{
    if (null == myJSON){
        _se.log.trace("SyntaxError: Error #1132: Invalid JSON parse input.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to reproduce the ***Finally*** stage in Haxe? ***Finally*** was quite important to me, I liked the way it worked in this given scenario, it stopped the application from crashing or pausing with a window pop-up of the error.

Preferably looking for a raw solution that works for both AS3 and Haxe.

Answer (score 4):

There is the `scopes` haxelib which I believe provides similar functionality to `try/catch/finally` with scope guards and protected blocks. See: https://bitbucket.org/parensoft/scopes

From the primitive protected/cleanup expressions example in their readme:

```
import scopes.Protect;

Protect.protect(PROT, CLEAN);
```

> CLEAN will always be executed when PROT exits. This includes normal
>   completion or an abrupt exit with an exception, or a return, break or
>   continue statement.
>
> Any abrupt exit from the CLEAN expression will shadow the previous
>   abrupt exit from the PROT expression, if any.
>
> The value of the Protect.protect(PROT, CLEAN) expression is the value
>   of the PROT expression if it completes; otherwise it's unspecified
>   (and unreachable as well).

Actually adding the `finally` keyword to Haxe has been discussed before: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3335 - however it looks like it is pending further discussion.

Comment: Thank you for the post, I was aware of the GitHub post, it has been nearly four years & the issue is closed.

Comment: Indeed, the process for proposing significant changes like that changed which is why it was closed there: https://haxe.org/blog/haxe-evolution-process/